# GAE Java 8 Runtime: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 68 in request URL

Tags: spring-mvc, google-app-engine, java-8, jetty-9, servlet-3.1

I use Spring MVC (not Spring Boot) for my Google App Engine REST based web-app. Today I [upgraded GAE Java runtime to 1.8](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime-java8#Java_Selecting_the_Java_runtime) (Java 8) and servlet-api 3.1. AppEngine SDK version 1.9.56.

All the spring beans load perfectly without any error. I get this exception while its serving a request:

```
GET http://localhost:9080/api/systems/urn:bnb:system:0ee64dc1-5dcd-46a5-aeaa-3d15858cb79e/details

2017-10-09 17:26:47.760:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:qtp823914581-19: /api/systems/urn:bnb:system:0ee64dc1-5dcd-46a5-aeaa-3d15858cb79e/details
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 68: C:\Amit\APP\app\apisvc\build\exploded-app\/api/systems/urn:bnb:system:0ee64dc1-5dcd-46a5-aeaa-3d15858cb79e/details/index.html
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.PathResource.<init>(PathResource.java:213)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.PathResource.addPath(PathResource.java:304)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.StaticFileFilter.getResource(StaticFileFilter.java:133)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.StaticFileFilter.maybeServeWelcomeFile(StaticFileFilter.java:172)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:96)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1751)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.doScope(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:597)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:283)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:108)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.execute(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:100)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.run(ManagedSelector.java:147)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And here is my appengine-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">

    <!-- Test GAE instance -->
    <application>webapp-1013</application>
    <version>1-2</version>
    <threadsafe>false</threadsafe>

    <runtime>java8</runtime>

    <system-properties>
        <property name="DEFAULT_ENCODING" value="UTF-8" />
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
    </system-properties>

    <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>

    <inbound-services>
        <service>warmup</service>
    </inbound-services>

</appengine-web-app>
```

I didn't face this problem when I was using Java 7 runtime with GAE. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are hitting a bug that affects the development app server on Windows (it does not affect apps deployed to production App Engine).  The bug is being tracked here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63595917

A fix for this is included in the upcoming SDK release, 1.9.58.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I will wait for SDK v1.9.58 to be available in Maven Repository.